# Apache error logs Need help to clear these errors

Tags: apache, centos, vps

Can some one take a look and help me what are these errors log I've found in my apache and some of my site also stop working

```
'<b>Deprecated</b>:  Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[Sun Aug 09 08:25:57 2015] [error] [client 66.249.79.11] <br />
[Sun Aug 09 08:25:57 2015] [error] [client 66.249.79.11] <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CDT/-5.0/DST' instead in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[Sun Aug 09 08:25:57 2015] [error] [client 66.249.79.11] <br />
[Sun Aug 09 08:25:57 2015] [error] [client 66.249.79.11] <b>Deprecated</b>:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[Sun Aug 09 08:26:23 2015] [error] [client 178.159.0.114] Cannot load the ionCube PHP Loader - it was built with configuration 2.2.0, whereas running engine is API220090626,NTS
[Sun Aug 09 08:26:23 2015] [error] [client 178.159.0.114] Zend Optimizer requires Zend Engine API version 220060519.
[Sun Aug 09 08:26:23 2015] [error] [client 178.159.0.114] The Zend Engine API version 220090626 which is installed, is newer.
[Sun Aug 09 08:26:23 2015] [error] [client 178.159.0.114] Contact Zend Technologies at http://www.zend.com/ for a later version of Zend Optimizer.
[Sun Aug 09 08:26:23 2015] [error] [client 178.159.0.114] 
[Sun Aug 09 08:26:23 2015] [error] [client 178.159.0.114] Failed loading /usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so:  /usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot load the ionCube PHP Loader - it was built with configuration 2.2.0, whereas running engine is API220090626,NTS
'
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have PHP 5.3.something and both the ionCube Loader and Zend component are built for an older version of PHP 5. There are two things, or possibly three, that you should really do:

1) Upgrade to PHP 5.5 or 5.6 as 5.3 reached end of life some time ago and is very old.

2) Install the ionCube Loader for PHP 5.5 and 5.6 from the ionCube site at http://ioncu.be/L and the Zend component if you need it to. There is a tool called the Loader wizard on the ionCube Loaders page that can help.

3) If PHP 5.3 is what your host is giving you and if there is no option to use a new version, and there are some hosting resellers out there like that, change your host IMMEDIATELY and get a reputable one that is up to date both with PHP and also operating system versions. A search at webhostingtalk.com would be one place to go to find a better one.